# Null Binary Tree Creation C/C++

Tags: c++, recursion, memory, tree, binary-tree

I need to create a binary tree with 7 layers so 128 leafs I guess. However I need to create it at the very beginning without adding nodes 1 by 1.
I wrote a recursive function in preorder I guess. But what is the problem is How can I end recursion when 7th layer has been created.Here what tried:

```
bool tree::create(node *ptr)
{
    ptr = NULL;
    if (ptr->right->right->right->right->right->right->right)
        return true;
    ptr->left = new node;
    ptr->right = new node;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    create(ptr->left);
    create(ptr->right);
}
```

However it is easily seen it occurs error when trying the read ptr->right while in first recursion since it is not created yet.

Is there any way to create it or should I give up which will cause me to start over the whole code.

Comment: Your signature should look like this `bool tree::create(node *& ptr){` if you want to change `ptr`. Also note `if (ptr->right->right->right->right->right->right->right)` calls undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code is a complete mess, I think you should start over the whole code, but now trying to understand what you are doing step by step. Programming by guessing does not work.

Comment: I think you mean memory violation that stated above with "undefined behavior" and you are right about calling with reference. Thank you

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz: No, he really meant UB. "access violation" is one possible (and fairly harmless) way it might be expressed.

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz an access violation is the safest thing that can happen here. If it succeeded that would be far more dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two statements

```
ptr = NULL;
if (ptr->right->right->right->right->right->right->right)
```

result in undefined behaviour and do not make sense.

You should include the magic number 7 in your function. Otherwise it is not clear how many levels you need to create in each recursive call of the function.

If to use "C approach" then the function can look like

```
void tree::create( node **ptr, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    { 
        *ptr = new node;
        ( *ptr )->left  = NULL;
        ( *ptr )->right = NULL;

        create( &( *ptr )->left,  n - 1 );
        create( &( *ptr )->right, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

Also in C++ you simply may use `node * &` instead of `node **`

```
void tree::create( node * &ptr, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    { 
        ptr = new node;
        ptr->left  = NULL;
        ptr->right = NULL;

        create( ptr->left,  n - 1 );
        create( ptr->right, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that is something average between C++ and C code.:)

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    size_t i;
    node() : i( ++n )
    {
        std::cout << "creating node " << i << std::endl;
    }

    ~node()
    {
        delete left;
        delete right;
        std::cout << "deleting node " << i << std::endl;
    }

    static size_t n;
};

size_t node::n;

void create( node **ptr, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    { 
        *ptr = new node;
        ( *ptr )->left  = NULL;
        ( *ptr )->right = NULL;

        create( &( *ptr )->left,  n - 1 );
        create( &( *ptr )->right, n - 1 );
    }
}

void clear( node **tree )
{
    delete *tree;
    *tree = nullptr;
}


int main()
{
    node *tree;

    create( &tree, 3 );

    clear( &tree );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
creating node 1
creating node 2
creating node 3
creating node 4
creating node 5
creating node 6
creating node 7
deleting node 3
deleting node 4
deleting node 2
deleting node 6
deleting node 7
deleting node 5
deleting node 1
```

Comment: my bad i forgot to do it. Thanks again!